# Vector drawable distorted

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable

I have many imageviews that use a vector drawable as it's source. For most of them it's material icons but when I imported a more complicated vector it shows up distorted on Lollipop devices but just fine on Jellybean devices. This is supposed to say SYSTEMS but clearly has problems.

[image: vector]

Layout:

```
<ImageView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/splash_logo"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo_small"
        tools:ignore="MissingPrefix"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

Gradle build file:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.android.example"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    generatedDensities = []
}

aaptOptions {
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
}
```

Vector drawable:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="160dp"
    android:height="40dp"
    android:viewportWidth="432.0"
    android:viewportHeight="108.0">
<path
    android:pathData="M247.77,92.34a4.5,4.5 0,0 0,4 2.09c2.26,0 3.64,-1.3 3.64,-2.91 0,-3.68 -8,-2.1 -8,-6.81 0,-2.22 2.14,-3.79 5.52,-3.79a6.67,6.67 0,0 1,3.76 0.94,5.37 5.37,0 0,0 -0.69,1.68h-0.3a3.1,3.1 0,0 0,-3 -1.88c-1.91,0 -3.28,1 -3.28,2.48 0,3.75 8,2.18 8,6.61 0,2.45 -2.31,4.51 -6.23,4.51a7.26,7.26 0,0 1,-4.2 -1.14,4.84 4.84,0 0,0 0.48,-1.78h0.31Z"
    android:fillColor="#fff"/>
<path
    android:pathData="M266.2,81.18a9.57,9.57 0,0 0,2.79 0c1.48,2.28 3.08,4.55 4.83,6.93a65,65 0,0 0,4.81 -6.93,4.85 4.85,0 0,0 2,0 99.26,99.26 0,0 0,-6.15 7.91c0,2 0.08,4.67 0.2,5.91a7.92,7.92 0,0 0,-2.49 0,46.6 46.6,0 0,0 0.2,-5.69C271.36,87.93 267.27,82.44 266.2,81.18Z"
    android:fillColor="#fff"/>
<path
    android:pathData="M290.21,92.34a4.5,4.5 0,0 0,4 2.09c2.26,0 3.64,-1.3 3.64,-2.91 0,-3.68 -8,-2.1 -8,-6.81 0,-2.22 2.13,-3.79 5.52,-3.79a6.69,6.69 0,0 1,3.77 0.94,5.28 5.28,0 0,0 -0.69,1.68h-0.31a3.1,3.1 0,0 0,-3 -1.88c-1.91,0 -3.28,1 -3.28,2.48 0,3.75 8,2.18 8,6.61 0,2.45 -2.32,4.51 -6.23,4.51a7.24,7.24 0,0 1,-4.19 -1.14,4.92 4.92,0 0,0 0.48,-1.78h0.3Z"
    android:fillColor="#fff"/>
<path
    android:pathData="M314.11,86.37q0,-2.07 -0.08,-4.15c-1.75,0 -4,0.08 -5.44,0.22a1.8,1.8 0,0 0,0.13 -0.64,1.91 1.91,0 0,0 -0.13,-0.62c2.19,0.06 4.37,0.1 6.56,0.1s4.38,0 6.56,-0.1a2,2 0,0 0,-0.13 0.64,1.85 1.85,0 0,0 0.13,0.62c-1.42,-0.14 -3.69,-0.22 -5.44,-0.22q-0.08,2.07 -0.08,4.15v3.45c0,1.72 0.1,3.47 0.2,5.19a9.29,9.29 0,0 0,-1.25 -0.1,9.19 9.19,0 0,0 -1.25,0.1c0.1,-1.72 0.2,-3.46 0.2,-5.19V86.37Z"
    android:fillColor="#fff"/>
<path
    android:pathData="M331.8,86.35c0,-1.72 -0.1,-3.47 -0.2,-5.17 1.52,0.06 3,0.1 4.55,0.1s3,0 4.53,-0.1a2.39,2.39 0,0 0,0 1.2c-2.13,-0.12 -3.38,-0.26 -6.69,-0.26 0,0.86 -0.1,1.56 -0.1,2.54s0,2.14 0,2.65c3,0 4.68,-0.1 6.18,-0.2a2.66,2.66 0,0 0,-0.08 0.62,2.5 2.5,0 0,0 0.08,0.6c-1.76,-0.14 -5,-0.18 -6.18,-0.18 0,0.48 0,1 0,2.91 0,1.52 0,2.5 0,3a58.72,58.72 0,0 0,6.87 -0.26,2.54 2.54,0 0,0 -0.08,0.62 2.22,2.22 0,0 0,0.08 0.58c-1.5,-0.06 -3,-0.1 -4.58,-0.1s-3.07,0 -4.62,0.1c0.1,-1.74 0.2,-3.49 0.2,-5.21V86.35Z"
    android:fillColor="#fff"/>
<path
    android:pathData="M353.24,80.92c2.31,3.77 4.7,7.29 7.3,11 1,-1.56 5.06,-7.33 7.55,-11h0.33c0.76,5.13 1.27,9.5 2.08,14.08a7.29,7.29 0,0 0,-2.39 0c-0.36,-3.59 -0.71,-6.91 -1.24,-10.34h-0.05c-2.31,3.35 -4.65,6.63 -6.66,10.24h-0.23c-2,-3.32 -4.32,-6.77 -6.53,-10.24h-0.05c-0.48,3.31 -1.19,8.08 -1.22,10.34a4.06,4.06 0,0 0,-1.78 0c0.89,-4.43 1.91,-9.84 2.47,-14.08h0.43Z"
    android:fillColor="#fff"/>
<path
    android:pathData="M380.75,92.34a4.51,4.51 0,0 0,4 2.09c2.26,0 3.63,-1.3 3.63,-2.91 0,-3.68 -8,-2.1 -8,-6.81 0,-2.22 2.14,-3.79 5.52,-3.79a6.66,6.66 0,0 1,3.76 0.94,5.44 5.44,0 0,0 -0.69,1.68h-0.3a3.11,3.11 0,0 0,-3 -1.88c-1.91,0 -3.28,1 -3.28,2.48 0,3.75 8,2.18 8,6.61 0,2.45 -2.31,4.51 -6.23,4.51A7.24,7.24 0,0 1,380 94.13a4.91,4.91 0,0 0,0.48 -1.78h0.3Z"
    android:fillColor="#fff"/>
</vector>
```

Comment: Hmmm... Why not using a simple TextView for displaying strings? A VectorDrawable seems much of an overkill, here.

Comment: @BobMalooga It's actually part of a larger vector image that has artwork as well. Only the section from the posted code looks distorted.

Comment: I'm experiencing this on a vector drawable asset only on Lollipop - does anyone else have other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to have been fixed with the latest version of Android Studio (2.0) and Build Tools (23.0.3). I also removed `generatedDensities = []` and `aaptOptions { additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors" }` as well as support and appcompat libraries, relying soley on the design library. I have tested on both Jellybean and Lollipop devices and while the vector preview still looks distorted in Android Studio, it shows up just fine on all physical devices. Seems like this issue was a bug on Google's end.