# How to use Adobe XD button design in Android Studio?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, svg, button

I have button design which created using Adobe XD. I want to use this design in my android button. How can do this. I can get this design as an .png or .svg. I don't want the background to deteriorate.

Comment: Do you want to set your .svg into your button?. If yes then covert .svg into vector drawable using vector assets of the android studio option. Then, use it as a background of the button

Comment: @KrishnaSony I use it but the picture is distorted.

Comment: Okay then put yours .png file in drawable and use as drawable in button background

Answer (score 1):

It depend how the design looks like in Adobe XD.
If your problem is decision how to use resource from XD as background so it will not "deteriorate", you have two options:

1. PNG: Download resource as .png and add in different sizes to adequate res folders. [Documentation about resources on Android](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources). Check part about resouces depending on `Screen pixel density`
2. SVG: Download resource as .svg and convert it to .xml in Android Studio to use as Vector Drawable. Then use it as a background of button. Vector Drawable will scale to the different resolutions without quality decrease.
   [image]

Comment: I use option 2.  But image Colors etc are getting up. The picture is distorted.

Comment: @uyarc Some issues with Vector Drawables which might be your problem:

- Min api 21 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34417843/how-to-use-vector-drawables-in-android-api-lower-21

- Distorted Vector Drawable https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36434492/vector-drawable-distorted

- Vector Drawable gradients are API 24+ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40872114/can-gradientcolor-be-used-to-define-a-gradient-for-a-fill-or-stroke-entirely-in